Is there a dongle to allow me to connect portable monitor via the single USB-C and let me connect the HDMI?
I've had UPERFECT K118 portable monitor for a while and it works extremely well. I connect it directly to my laptop (I have a Surface Pro 7 which I keep plugged in to power everything) via a standard USB-C to USB-C that was included with the monitor. That's the only cable I need, it supplies both power and the display connection.
Are there any dongles that would allow me to continue connecting my portable monitor via the single USB-C cable only and let me connect the HDMI, for a total of 3 screens (including laptop)?
I get power but no signal. Using the second dongle with unpowered USB-C port, the same happens. However, nothing happens in the latter's powered USB-C port.

As far as I'm aware you would need to use DisplayPort to daisychain in that manner.  There should be USB-C hubs that support DP1.3.
